# Trouble connecting "sqlite3" in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following database saved as `data_db.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE protein (
    accession   varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    species_id  int,  -- NCBI taxonomic code
    mass        float,
    description varchar(100),
    seq         varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (species_id) REFERENCES species (species_id)
);

CREATE TABLE protein_keywords (
    accession varchar(20),
    keyword   varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (accession, keyword),
    FOREIGN KEY (accession) REFERENCES protein(accession)
);

INSERT INTO 'protein' VALUES('7UP2_DROME',7227,76814,'Steroid receptor seven-up, isoform A (Nuclear receptor subfamily 2 group F member 3, isoform A)','MCASPSTAPGFFNPRPQSGAELSAFDIGLSRSMGLGVPPHSAWHEPPASLGGHLHAASAGPGTTTGSVATGGGGTTPSSVASQQSAVIKQDLSCPSLNQAGSGHHPGIKEDLSSSLPSANGGSAGGHHSGSGSGSGSGVNPGHGSDMLPLIKGHGQDMLTSIKGQPTGCGSTTPSSQANSSHSQSSNSGSQIDSKQNIECVVCGDKSSGKHYGQFTCEGCKSFFKRSVRRNLTYSCRGSRNCPIDQHHRNQCQYCRLKKCLKMGMRREAVQRGRVPPTQPGLAGMHGQYQIANGDPMGIAGFNGHSYLSSYISLLLRAEPYPTSRYGQCMQPNNIMGIDNICELAARLLFSAVEWAKNIPFFPELQVTDQVALLRLVWSELFVLNASQCSMPLHVAPLLAAAGLHASPMAADRVVAFMDHIRIFQEQVEKLKALHVDSAEYSCLKAIVLFTTGKLLDILYKDVPALLTKVSALLGKGSTASNDDVLAVVRDHLDELNRQEQESQAQQQAPLHLAAFMNCVAGVEAAVQQAEQAQVPTSSASASVSAPLVPSAGSAFSSCQAKSAGSEMDLLASLYAQAQATPPSSGGGDASGHNNSSGLGASLPTQSQSGSSSRNLTASPLSTSLATAPAPASASAPAPVPTSSVAQVPVPAPVPVTSSASSSSLGGGAYQTPSAAAAAAAMFHYQTPPRAAFGSAFDMFHHSTPFGVGVGHAHALAHSSGSGSASFGSPSYRYSPYSLAGSRWQL');

INSERT INTO 'protein' VALUES('E75BB_DROME',7227,151292,'Ecdysone-induced protein 75B, isoform B (E75-C) (Nuclear receptor subfamily 1 group D member 3, isoform B)','MEAVQAAAAATSSGGSSGSVPGSGSGSASKLIKTEPIDFEMLHLEENERQQDIEREPSSSNSNSNSNSLTPQRYTHVQVQTVPPRQPTGLTTPGGTQKVILTPRVEYVQQRATSSTGGGMKHVYSQQQGTAASRSAPPETTALLTTTSGTPQIIITRTLPSNQHLSRRHSASPSALHHYQQQQPQRQQSPPPLHHQQQQQQQHVRVIRDGRLYDEATVVVAARRHSVSPPPLHHHSRSAPVSPVIARRGGAAAYMDQQYQQRQTPPLAPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQYISTGVPPPTAAARKFVVSTSTRHVNVIASNHFQQQQQQHQAQQHQQQHQQHQQHQQHVIASVSSSSSSSAIGSGGSSSSHIFRTPVVSSSSSSNMHHQQQQQQQQSSLGNSVMRPPPPPPPPKVKHASSSSSGNSSSSNTNNSSSSSNGEEPSSSIPDLEFDGTTVLCRVCGDKASGFHYGVHSCEGCKGFFRRSIQQKIQYRPCTKNQQCSILRINRNRCQYCRLKKCIAVGMSRDAVRFGRVPKREKARILAAMQQSTQNRGQQRALATELDDQPRLLAAVLRAHLETCEFTKEKVSAMRQRARDCPSYSMPTLLACPLNPAPELQSEQEFSQRFAHVIRGVIDFAGMIPGFQLLTQDDKFTLLKAGLFDALFVRLICMFDSSINSIICLNGQVMRRDAIQNGANARFLVDSTFNFAERMNSMNLTDAEIGLFCAIVLITPDRPGLRNLELIEKMYSRLKGCLQYIVAQNRPDQPEFLAKLLETMPDLRTLSTLHTEKLVVFRTEHKELLRQQMWSMEDGNNSDGQQNKSPSGSWADAMDVEAAKSPLGSVSSTESADLDYGSPSSSQPQGVSLPSPPQQQPSALASSAPLLAATLSGGCPLRNRANSGSSGDSGAAEMDIVGSHAHLTQNGLTITPIVRHQQQQQQQQQIGILNNAHSRNLNGGHAMCQQQQQHPQLHHHLTAGAARYRKLDSPTDSGIESGNEKNECKAVSSGGSSSCSSPRSSVDDALDCSDAAANHNQVVQHPQLSVVSVSPVRSPQPSTSSHLKRQIVEDMPVLKRVLQAPPLYDTNSLMDEAYKPHKKFRALRHREFETAEADASSSTSGSNSLSAGSPRQSPVPNSVATPPPSAASAAAGNPAQSQLHMHLTRSSPKASMASSHSVLAKSLMAEPRMTPEQMKRSDIIQNYLKRENSTAASSTTNGVGNRSPSSSSTPPPSAVQNQQRWGSSSVITTTCQQRQQSVSPHSNGSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTSSNCSSSSASSCQYFQSPHSTSNGTSAPASSSSGSNSATPLLELQVDIADSAQPLNLSKKSPTPPPSKLHALVAAANAVQRYPTLSADVTVTASNGGPPSAAASPAPSSSPPASVGSPNPGLSAAVHKVMLEA');

INSERT INTO 'protein' VALUES('COT2_MOUSE',10090,45571,'COUP transcription factor 2 (COUP-TF2) (Apolipoprotein AI regulatory protein 1) (ARP-1) (COUP transcription factor II) (COUP-TF II) (Nuclear receptor subfamily 2 group F member 2)','MAMVVSTWRDPQDEVPGSQGSQASQAPPVPGPPPGAPHTPQTPGQGGPASTPAQTAAGGQGGPGGPGSDKQQQQQHIECVVCGDKSSGKHYGQFTCEGCKSFFKRSVRRNLSYTCRANRNCPIDQHHRNQCQYCRLKKCLKVGMRREAVQRGRMPPTQPTHGQFALTNGDPLNCHSYLSGYISLLLRAEPYPTSRFGSQCMQPNNIMGIENICELAARMLFSAVEWARNIPFFPDLQITDQVALLRLTWSELFVLNAAQCSMPLHVAPLLAAAGLHASPMSADRVVAFMDHIRIFQEQVEKLKALHVDSAEYSCLKAIVLFTSDACGLSDVAHVESLQEKSQCALEEYVRSQYPNQPTRFGKLLLRLPSLRTVSSSVIEQLFFVRLVGKTPIETLIRDMLLSGSSFNWPYMAIQ');
```

Then, I try to connect to this database in python as follow:

```
import sqlite3

db_file = 'data_db.sql'


def get_connection(db_file):    
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return connection, cursor

def get_protein(cursor):
    cursor.execute('protein' VALUES('7UP2_DROME',722))
    return cursor.fetchall()

def main(db_file):
    con, cur = get_connection(db_file)
    protein = get_protein(cur)
    for row in protein:
        print(row)
    con.close()
```

However, I get the following error-message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    main('data_db.sql')
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3340000\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3340000\file.py", line 16, in main
    con, cur = get_connection(db_file)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3340000\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3340000\file.py", line 7, in get_connection
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
AttributeError: module 'sqlite3' has no attribute 'connect'
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to connect to the database in order to make calculations,

Comment: Sounds like a name clash. Is there anything named `sqlite3` in your project folder?

Comment: But I have no file called sqlite in my folder. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Add a `print(sqlite3.__file__)` just after the import and post the output.

Comment: C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py

Comment: But that's not were the file I'm changing is stored, It's stored in a different folder. However, I neew to change the directory in some way. Is that correct?

Comment: No - don't change directory - check where your PYTHONPATH environment variable is pointing - my guess is that it includes `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib` for some reason - remove that entry and then run your program again.

BTW - changing directory wouldn't help unless you changed directory to the exact fold that contains the sqlite module (which defeats the point0.

Answer (score 0):

```
with sqlite3.connect('data_db.sql') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('SELECT * from protein')
return cur.rowcount
```

Try the above instead of your get_connection and get_protein methods.

Comment: I will try that. I will respond in a few minutes.

Comment: There is somethin wrong with the indentation. Are you sure the code should look as above (see edit)? The probelm relates to the " return cur.rowcount".

Comment: try that? I don't have python installed on my mobile to test, but now am back on computer

Comment: Do you mean 'SELECT * from protein', right (instead of '')? When I try to press run, I still get error for the return-statement. I'm using a Python 3.8.2 Shell as my IDLE.

Comment: Any ideas? Is it possible to connect in a different approach also?

Comment: Had an extra "'" bleh :(

Comment: But let's assume the database contains 1000 proteins. Yhen I can't add them manually to the cursor as we did now. How should I solve this?

Comment: Your query was a select, that's to retrieve, adding requires an insert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226181/discussion-between-hd1-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 0):

1/
1/data_db.sql file (updated)

```
CREATE TABLE protein (
    accession   varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    species_id  int,  -- NCBI taxonomic code
    mass        float,
    description varchar(100),
    seq         varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (species_id) REFERENCES species (species_id)
);

CREATE TABLE protein_keywords (
    accession varchar(20),
    keyword   varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (accession, keyword),
    FOREIGN KEY (accession) REFERENCES protein(accession)
);

INSERT INTO protein VALUES('7UP2_DROME',7227,76814,'Steroid receptor seven-up, isoform A (Nuclear receptor subfamily 2 group F member 3, isoform A)','MCASPSTAPGFFNPRPQSGAELSAFDIGLSRSMGLGVPPHSAWHEPPASLGGHLHAASAGPGTTTGSVATGGGGTTPSSVASQQSAVIKQDLSCPSLNQAGSGHHPGIKEDLSSSLPSANGGSAGGHHSGSGSGSGSGVNPGHGSDMLPLIKGHGQDMLTSIKGQPTGCGSTTPSSQANSSHSQSSNSGSQIDSKQNIECVVCGDKSSGKHYGQFTCEGCKSFFKRSVRRNLTYSCRGSRNCPIDQHHRNQCQYCRLKKCLKMGMRREAVQRGRVPPTQPGLAGMHGQYQIANGDPMGIAGFNGHSYLSSYISLLLRAEPYPTSRYGQCMQPNNIMGIDNICELAARLLFSAVEWAKNIPFFPELQVTDQVALLRLVWSELFVLNASQCSMPLHVAPLLAAAGLHASPMAADRVVAFMDHIRIFQEQVEKLKALHVDSAEYSCLKAIVLFTTGKLLDILYKDVPALLTKVSALLGKGSTASNDDVLAVVRDHLDELNRQEQESQAQQQAPLHLAAFMNCVAGVEAAVQQAEQAQVPTSSASASVSAPLVPSAGSAFSSCQAKSAGSEMDLLASLYAQAQATPPSSGGGDASGHNNSSGLGASLPTQSQSGSSSRNLTASPLSTSLATAPAPASASAPAPVPTSSVAQVPVPAPVPVTSSASSSSLGGGAYQTPSAAAAAAAMFHYQTPPRAAFGSAFDMFHHSTPFGVGVGHAHALAHSSGSGSASFGSPSYRYSPYSLAGSRWQL');
```

run `sqlite3 data.db` in cmd or shell or whatever, and at prompt `.read data_db.sql`
This will CREATE the db on your disk.

2/ Python part : interacting with the db (see the doc please ! https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)

```py
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect('data.db') as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM protein')
    print(c.fetchall())
```

- 

You then have to learn how to formulate your SQL queries (and i can help too) !

Let me know how this helps you.

Comment: Should I have the full path in cmd? When running sqlite3 data.db I simply get"sqlite3" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch. Yes' I'm on Windows

Comment: you're on Windows ? https://sqlite.org/cli.html Open your cmd in the directory where your .sql stands.

Comment: Ok, not were the python file is? I have the sql installation in one directory and the python file in a different directory.

Comment: Simpler if everything is in the same place. Or you have to work with relative adresses. Familiar with this ?

Comment: Ok, so now the .py file, the data_db.sql and the sqlite3 program file are all in the same folder.

Comment: let me know if everything works. I'm reproducing your case on a Win machine

Comment: Do you mean I should write sqlite3 data_db.sql instead of sqlite3 data.db, right? Beacuse the file name is data_db.sql. I have made that, and the sqlite3 program has started from the cmd.

Comment: from the cmd, write `sqlite3 data_db`. Then from the sqlite prompt, write `.read data_db.sql` I did it on my son's win machine, it works, it creates the `data.db` in the current directory. You can install sqlitebrowser if you want to inspect your db. Won't let you till it works, we are close !

Comment: Ok, I made that. I got "Usage .read FILE". I have already the EMACS, so I know how the db looks like. What's next step?

Comment: good carry on, now `.read data_db.sql` If the `data.db` has been created on your disc, you can now proceed with the python part : you can now query your database

Comment: Yes, I have written that once already in the sqlite promt. Should I repeat that?

Comment: Has `data.db` appeared in your file navigator ? If so, you can now execute the python part of my above answer. We can then have a quick tchat about SQL queries if you want.

Comment: Where can I see the file navigator? When I printed .read data_db.sql in the sql-prompt from cmd, I got Usage: .read FILE

Comment: How do you navigate in your computer ? You know this app where you see the files, delete them, change their name. This kind of app. You should see in the same rep your py file, your data_db.sql and something named data.db

Comment: Ok, but I have no file called data.db in my folder, where I store the files, If that´s what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226182/discussion-between-smeden-and-john-doe).

Comment: Now that your db has been created, take the python part in my answer above, execute it, and you will see an answer to your sql query (tested on liux and win systems both). You should manage the rest four yourself... You are one move away from success

Comment: Sure, but when I put that code in the file "Laboration_4.py" and run it using an IDLE, I get the error-message as explained in the chat.

Comment: Weird. Here, everything works fine with your codes. Can't any(physical)body help you around ? I have to leave you on that, can't see how help you further.... Best luck on that. Let me know if you succeed. Don't forget to vote for my answer in that case !